# phonegap native android application issue

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi I am developing a native android application in phone-gap ,in that application I want to upload a image file through chose file button when I click the button I want to open the device gallery but the gallery window is not opening.I can open the gallery windows when I load through browser in device but cant make it natively for android,so please help me find solution for this.

Will the phone gap scripting file changes for various platform or it needs any plugin files to be added for various platforms in phone gap or I need to add any **cordova.js** files to root files(like WWW).

I have doubt that any kind of version compatibility issues in phone gap or device so please help me.

for further details i will add my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery/plugins/jqtransform/jqtransform.css" />
  <title> Mobile</title>
  <script src="js/jquery/jquery162min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery/plugins/accordion/jqueryui1814custommin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/plugins/jqtransform/jqtransform.js" ></script>
  <script src="js/mgeneral.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../js/pl/plupload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../js/pl/plupload.html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    /*Set skin for select, options and checkbox*/
    $('.skinnable').jqTransform({ imgPath: 'img/' });

    $('#apply-to-selection-2').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Logout();
        if (RTNCODE)
            window.location = "index.html";

    });

    /*table row select*/
    $("table.grid thead tr th.col-row-select input").click(function () {
        if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("table.grid tbody tr td.col-row-select input").each(function () {
                $(this).attr("checked", true);
                $(this).change();
            });
        }
        else {
            $("table.grid tbody tr td.col-row-select input").each(function () {
                $(this).attr("checked", false);
                $(this).change();
            });
        }
    });
    /*END table row select*/
    /*Create accordion*/
    $(".accordion").accordion({
        header: ".accordion-tab",
        collapsible: true,
        active: 0,
        autoHeight: false
    });

});
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

     $(function () {  //image loader
         var uploaderimage = new plupload.Uploader({
             // General settings
             runtimes: 'html5',
             container: 'imagecontainer',
             browse_button: 'pickfiles',
             url: '/imageupload.ashx?mobile=true',
             multi_selection: false,
             max_file_size: '10mb',
             //chunk_size: '1mb',
             multipart: true,
             urlstream_upload: true,
             // Specify what files to browse for
             filters: [
                             { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" }
             ]


         });

         uploaderimage.init();


         uploaderimage.bind('FilesAdded', function (up, files) {
             //            showmodalmask();
             uploaderimage.start();
             $('.imgpre').show();
             $('.imgcpl').hide();
         });

         uploaderimage.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file) {
             if (uploaderimage.total.uploaded == uploaderimage.files.length) {
                 //            $('.btnrefresh').click();
                 $('.imgcpl').show();
                 $('.imgpre').hide();
              }
          });
       });
    </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="frame">
    <div class="frame-border-top"></div>
     <div class="frame-border-middle">
      <div class="cute" style="">
        <h1 class="header" style="color:transparent; width:270px; height:20px;">
  </h1></div>
  <!-- MENU  START  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -->

  <div id="tabs-2" style="background-color:Black; border:1px solid #363636;">
        <div style="margin-left:-15px; margin-top:-6px;">
            <div class="form-row padding-lr-5" style="text-align:center;">
              <div id="imagecontainer" >

                <div id="filelist"></div>

                <br />

                <a id="pickfiles" href="#" style="background-color: #447cd1; color: white; border: 2px solid #113b7c; border-radius: 12px; padding: 6px 10px; font-size: 12pt; text-decoration: none">Select file</a>

            </div>
                <br />
                <div class="holderloderp imgpre" style="display:none"><img src="../images/pnl-preloader2.gif" width="25" height="25" alt="" class="pnl-preloader2" /></div>
                <div class="imgcpl" style="color: green; display: none" >Complete</div>
            </div>
              <div class="clear" style="height:25px;"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>   
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the FileTransfer object of the phonegap API which will do the upload to your server using any server side script file handler.

[Look at this link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer)

Comment: I have tried that link code but page is not loading. I am getting error [link](http://goo.gl/a4SAlR)